# I want to find the Locator type with locator content in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to find the Locator type with locator content in selenium. The following is the function which i wrote to get the locator type by passing locator content.

When i execute `Verify.java` it will go for `Function.java` and from there it will go to `Element.java` find the element locator type and return to function, and in function i will do the necessary operation like sendkeys or click.

In the `Verify.java` i have given the Xpath of textbox and button. My intention is to go and check whether the locator content which i pass belongs to which locator.

It is stopping by checking the first `if` itself and not going to `catch` block also and not moving to `else if` to verify other locator type. If i comment from first `if` up-to Xpath if its working. It is not looping and checking.

Can anyone suggest me the solution?

```
(Testcase) Verify.Java
----------------------
package cm;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class Verify extends Function{
    @Test
    public void Check(){
        Browser("Chrome", "https://www.google.co.in");
        Enter("//*[@id='lst-ib']", "Karthick");
        Click(".//*[@id='sblsbb']");
    }
}


Function.Java
-------------
package cm;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
public class Function extends Element{
    public void Enter(String LocatorContent, String Value) {
        FindElement(LocatorContent).sendKeys(Value);
    }
    public void Click(String LocatorContent) {
        FindElement(LocatorContent).click();
    }
}


Element.Java
------------
package cm;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
public class Element extends Browser {
    public Element()
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public WebElement FindElement(String LocatorContent){
        //this.driver = driver;
        WebElement elemen = null;

        if (driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) {
            try {
                elemen = driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorContent));
                System.out.println("element locator is id");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Element Not Found given with Locator Id : "+LocatorContent);
            }
            return elemen;
        }
        else if (driver.findElement(By.name(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) {
            try {
                elemen = driver.findElement(By.name(LocatorContent));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Element Not Found given with Locator Name : "+LocatorContent);
            }
            return elemen;
        }
        else if (driver.findElement(By.className(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) {
            try {
                elemen = driver.findElement(By.className(LocatorContent));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Element Not Found given with Locator ClassName : "+LocatorContent);
            }
            return elemen;
        }
        else if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) {
            try {
                elemen = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(LocatorContent));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Element Not Found given with Locator Css : "+LocatorContent);
            }
            return elemen;
        }
        else if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) {
            try {
                elemen = driver.findElement(By.xpath(LocatorContent));
                System.out.println("It Found the element "+LocatorContent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Element Not Found given with Locator Xpath : "+LocatorContent);
            }
            return elemen;
        }
        else if (driver.findElement(By.linkText(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) {
            try {
                elemen = driver.findElement(By.linkText(LocatorContent));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Element Not Found given with Locator LinkText : "+LocatorContent);
            }
            return elemen;
        }
        else if(driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) {
            {
                try {
                    elemen = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(LocatorContent));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Element Not Found given with Locator PartialLinkText : "+LocatorContent);
                }
                return elemen;
            }
        }
        return elemen;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below updated code, hope this will work.

```
public WebElement FindElement(String LocatorContent) throws Exception{
    this.driver = driver;
    WebElement elemen = null;
    try { 
        if (driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
            elemen = driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorContent));                
            System.out.println("element locator is id"); 
            return elemen;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ }
    try {    
        if (driver.findElement(By.name(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
            elemen = driver.findElement(By.name(LocatorContent)); 
            System.out.println("element locator is name"); 
            return elemen;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ }
    try {   
        if (driver.findElement(By.className(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
            elemen = driver.findElement(By.className(LocatorContent)); 
            System.out.println("element locator is className"); 
            return elemen;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ }
    try {  
        if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
            elemen = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(LocatorContent)); 
            System.out.println("element locator is cssSelector"); 
            return elemen;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ }
    try {
        if (driver.findElement(By.linkText(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
            elemen = driver.findElement(By.linkText(LocatorContent)); 
            System.out.println("element locator is linkText"); 
            return elemen;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ }
    try {
        if (driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
            elemen = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(LocatorContent)); 
            System.out.println("element locator is partialLinkText"); 
            return elemen;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ }
    try {
        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
            elemen = driver.findElement(By.xpath(LocatorContent)); 
            System.out.println("element locator is xpath");
            return elemen;
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { }      
    if (elemen.equals(null))
        throw new Exception("Please not found");
    return elemen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not loop as first (Below) condition generate exception when element not found and code break as you have not handled it.

```
if (driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed())
```

You should create function by checking string (locator) like below:

```
public WebElement ByLocator(String locator) {
    By result = null;
    if (locator.startsWith("//")) {
        result = By.xpath(locator);
    } else if (locator.startsWith("css=")) {
        result = By.cssSelector(locator.replace("css=", ""));
    } else if (locator.startsWith("id=")) {
        result = By.id(locator.replace("id=", ""));
    } else{
       result = By.name(locator);
    }
    return driver.findElement(result );
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Hi Sadik, I am not going to give "id='' " " or "css= " " ". I will just pass the value as mentioned in the code. Then can i use this code.

Comment: In you code it increase execution time as it was finding element in sequence, suppose that if you are passing linkText then it will check previous condition which will take some time. So the goof approach is that you mention some flag in string (locator ) and after identify locator type  apply find element function

Comment: If you have using same your code then you should add you conditional code in try catch blog like:  try {

if (driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) {
            
                elemen = driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorContent));
                System.out.println("element locator is id");           
            
        }
 } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Element Not Found given with Locator Id : "+LocatorContent);
            }

return elemen;

Comment: Its working fine with the above code you gave but its only for id how can i use it for various locators like xpath, css, linktext..in the try. Can you tell me

Comment: above code will work for css , name, xpath and id , add more condition for linktext etc

Comment: try { 
   if (driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
    elemen = driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorContent)); 
    System.out.println("element locator is id"); 
   }
   if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
    elemen = driver.findElement(By.xpath(LocatorContent)); 
    System.out.println("element locator is xpath"); 
   }
  } 
  catch (Exception e) { 
   System.out.println("Element Not Found given with Locator Id : "+LocatorContent); 
  } 
  return elemen;

Comment: I can't add in comments so i will post as one more question

Comment: Its not going to the last exception "Pleasenot found"

Answer (score 0):

```
Latest edited
-------------    
package cm;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    public class Ele extends Browser {

        public WebElement FindElement(String LocatorContent) throws Exception{
            this.driver = driver;
            WebElement elemen = null;
            try { 
                if (driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
                    elemen = driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorContent)); 
                    System.out.println("element locator is id"); 
                }
                else if (driver.findElement(By.name(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
                    elemen = driver.findElement(By.name(LocatorContent)); 
                    System.out.println("element locator is name"); 
                }
                else if (driver.findElement(By.className(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
                    elemen = driver.findElement(By.className(LocatorContent)); 
                    System.out.println("element locator is className"); 
                }
                else if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
                    elemen = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(LocatorContent)); 
                    System.out.println("element locator is cssSelector"); 
                }
                else if (driver.findElement(By.linkText(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
                    elemen = driver.findElement(By.linkText(LocatorContent)); 
                    System.out.println("element locator is linkText"); 
                }
                else if (driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
                    elemen = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(LocatorContent)); 
                    System.out.println("element locator is partialLinkText"); 
                }
                else if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
                    elemen = driver.findElement(By.xpath(LocatorContent)); 
                    System.out.println("element locator is xpath"); 
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) { 
                 if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(LocatorContent)).isDisplayed()) { 
                    elemen = driver.findElement(By.xpath(LocatorContent)); 
                    System.out.println("Element locator is xpath"); 
                }
                //System.out.println("Element Not Found given with Locator : "+LocatorContent); 
            }
            return elemen;
        }
    }
```